# Check against regular expressions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm wondering how to check for regular expressions in Ruby. I would like to check files where lines are in this format:

```
id: 123456 synset: word1,word2,etc
```

The number of digits of the integer doesn't matter. How many words are in `synset` doesn't matter either.

Am I supposed to use [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union)?

Comment: If these don't matter, what *does* matter?

Comment: What do you mean _check_ files? Check if they're true or you need to extract those lines?

Comment: just having `id: ` + number  and a space + `synset: ` + words separated by commas

Comment: It looks like it's space separated pairs, which is a terrible format. Double check there's no hard tabs in the file, that would make more sense. Also, is there any cases where the values are quoted to allow spaces? Are you sure this isn't malformatted YAML?

Comment: lol im sure it's malformatted but I can't do anything about it. I can't arbitrate what it looks like. Someone else is giving the data to me

Answer (score 1):

Regex would be handy here:

```
str = 'id: 123456 synset: word1,word2,etc'
m = str.match(/\Aid: (\d+) synset: (.+)\z/)
id, synset = m.captures
id
 => "123456" 
synset
 => "word1,word2,etc"
```

Or you could split the string into an array:

```
arr = str.split
_, id, _, synset = arr
id
 => "123456" 
synset
 => "word1,word2,etc"
```

Answer (score 0):

**./file1.rb:**

```
id: 123456 synset: word1,word2
id: 123456 synset: word1,word2
a;sdlkfjasdlkfj
id: 123456 synset: word1,word2
```

**./file2.rb**

```
file = File.new('./file1.rb','r+')
p file.grep(/^id: \d+ synset: (\w+,?)+$/)
#[
# id: 123456 synset: word1,word2,
# id: 123456 synset: word1,word2,
# id: 123456 synset: word1,word2"
#]
```

Uses [Enumerable#grep](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) to return an array of only the lines which match the regex.